# Upgrade to Web3 Library Version 4.1.x Causing Contract Function Transaction Failures via Metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask, truffle-contract

I am facing a very strange error and I am still unable to figure out after spending more than 2 days. I am using truffle framework and latest version of Web3 library which is version 4.1.2.

- I am using Truffle Develop Network:  http://127.0.0.1:9545/
- Wallet I am using: Metamask (with custom rpc network connecting to truffle)
- Account Address: I have imported Truffle develop user account on the metamask.

Web3 library not working

- New NPM Web3 Package : 4.1.2 or 4.1.1 or 4.1.0 ( I have installed latest versions using npm install web3 but none is working after 4.1.x )

Web 3 library which are working fine.

- OLD NPM Web3 Package : npm install web3@1.10.0 or npm install web3@4.0.1   (If I install these packages then everything works fine)

my contract code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0; 

contract Dummy {

string dummydata;

constructor()  
{
    dummydata = "test";
         
}
 function testdummyinsert(string calldata _dumy) public {

    dummydata = _dumy;
}

function getdummy() public view returns (string memory _ret) {
    return dummydata;
}

}
```

My html page statically loading these libraries on the page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

My html page button trigger to send transaction to blockchain

```
//trigger
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="onSubmitForm();">
```

This is a JS function onSubmitForm

```
async function onSubmitForm()
{

const _gasPrices = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();

const _gas = await mycontract.methods.testdummyinsert(fname).estimateGas({ from:userAddress});

const transaction = await mycontract.methods.testdummyinsert(fname).send({ from:userAddress, gasPrice: _gasPrices, gas: _gas });

}
```

I have tried promises, callbacks and tried all kinds code but for some reason Web3 version 4.X is not working at all for sending these simple transaction. The moment I degraded web3 npm package everything works fine. **In 4.X version calling blockchain network works perfectly fine but only issue comes when you want to change the state by sending a transaction to the network.**

Attached is the error picture [image]

> Uncaught (in promise) Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
> {"transactionHash":"0x50d17c29acf97e8fd0dfe84a8b37908b33a830463a895d6e76747cf1df190b83","transactionIndex":"0","blockNumber":"20","blockHash":"0xb8ff092abe1d312252803222d76fdf52dca6001e38be49f358b615941e2aa15e","from":"0x1a84bb86ebb0c6fc44a620c2869e776b3dd3c36a","to":"0x809f14942a3b5c6240fa94939c56c2018161624e","cumulativeGasUsed":"21069","gasUsed":"21069","logs":[],"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","status":"0","effectiveGasPrice":"2000000000","type":"2"}
> at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:2:547663
> at Generator.next ()
> at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:2:547312
> at new Promise ()
> at n (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:2:547057)
> at t.getTransactionError (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:2:547479)
> at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:2:529773
> at Generator.next ()
> at s (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js:2:521726)

any ideas how to fix this problem using latest Web 4.x version?